# Getting error "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()", while checking existing email and mobile

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to register a user, but first I check if mobile and email is already registered. All other validations are done by jQuery and a request is sent by Ajax to this PHP page. Everything is working fine if there is a new user, but that existing email and mobile checking part is not working. I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()

How can I fix it?

#### Code

```
<?php
    require('db_connection.php');
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $hashed_password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $sql = "SELECT `user_email`, `user_mobile` FROM `users` where `user_email` = ? OR `user_mobile` = ? LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $mobile);
        $stmt->bind_result($email, $mobile);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
            $row = $stmt->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            if(isset($row['user_email']) == $email){
                echo "email exists";
                //exit();
            }
            if(isset($row['user_mobile']) == $mobile){
                echo "mobile exists";
                //exit();
            }
        }else{
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `users`(`user_name`, `user_email`, `user_mobile`, `user_password`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $email, $mobile, $hashed_password);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "successfull";
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: [fetch_array belongs to mysqli_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php), not mysqli_stmt. You need to [get the result from the statement first](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

Comment: I tried with get_result() function also but not able to do it , can you please show in how to do it in my code please?

Comment: What does "not able to" mean? What did you try and what went wrong? It's only a tiny change: `$result = $stmt->get_result(); ... $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: @ADyson I did exactly this before posting the question here but in this code what you wrote I'm getting always email exists even if I enter different email but same mobile.

Comment: Well that's a step forward from getting an error. But next, `if(isset($row['user_email']) == $email)` makes no sense. `isset()` returns true or false. So basically you're asking it "does the $email variable exist" - to which the answer is always yes. Just write `if($row['user_email'] == $email)` instead. The `isset` isn't necessary. Same for the mobile test.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the reply, I already figured out what I did wrong and you wont believe me that I wrote the correct code 5 hrs back and didnt use "isset" and code was working perfectly except chrome network tab shown some warning on my page request, I google the warning tried to find out then I got to using that "isset" part. Seems like I messed up my working code and spent 6 hrs for nothing :(

Comment: We've all been there, sorry it ended up like that. So it's all working now, then?

Comment: @ADyson yes everything working fine now, Thank you again. Tell me one more thing that bind_result() is necessary in my code or not. Also any good tutorial on session() if you know any.

Comment: I don't think bind_result is necessary for you, since you are using get_result. I don't know any specific Session tutorials no, but I'm sure Google will suggest plenty. Good luck in your future work.